# Get static ipaddress, subnetmask, and gateway when media is disconnected

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way to query via the command line what the current ip address, subnet mask, and default gateway are when the media is disconnect from the port?

I have tired `ipconfig`,

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

`netsh interface ip show addresses` which does show the gateway but not the subnet or ip address,

```
Configuration for interface "Local Area Connection"
    DHCP enabled:                         No
    Default Gateway:                      192.168.6.17
    Gateway Metric:                       1
    InterfaceMetric:                      5
```

and `netsh interface ip show config`

```
Configuration for interface "Local Area Connection"
    DHCP enabled:                         No
    Default Gateway:                      192.168.6.17
    Gateway Metric:                       1
    InterfaceMetric:                      5
    Statically Configured DNS Servers:    None
    Register with which suffix:           Primary only
    Statically Configured WINS Servers:   None
```

The GUI shows the ip addess, subnet mask, and default gateway when the media is disconnected. Is there a command to get the same information on the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the ip address and subnet mask run the following command.

```
> netsh interface ip dump

# ----------------------------------
# IPv4 Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface ipv4

reset
set global icmpredirects=enabled
add route prefix=0.0.0.0/0 interface="Local Area Connection" nexthop=192.168.7.12 metric=1 publish=Yes
add address name="Local Area Connection" address=192.168.7.34 mask=255.255.255.128


popd
# End of IPv4 configuration
```

The IP Address is `address=192.168.7.34`, the Subtnet Mask is `mask=255.255.255.128`, and the Deafault Gateway is `nexthop=192.168.7.12`.